# Does each call to `yylex()` generate a token or all the tokens for the input?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexer

I am trying to understand how flex works under the hood.

- In the following first example,  it seems that `main()` calls `yylex()` only once, and `yylex()`  generates all the tokens for the entire input.
- In the second example, it seems that `main()` calls `yylex()`  once per token generated, and `yylex()`  generates a token per call.

Does each call to `yylex()`  generate a token or all the tokens for the input?

Why is `yylex()` called different number of times in the two examples?

I heard that `yylex()` is like a coroutine, and each call to it will resume with the rest of the input left from last call and generate a token. In that sense, how does the first example calls `yylex()` just once and generate all the tokens in the input?

```
/* just like Unix wc */
%{
int chars = 0;
int words = 0;
int lines = 0;
%}
%%
[a-zA-Z]+  { words++; chars += strlen(yytext); }
\n         { chars++; lines++; }
.          { chars++; }
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  yylex();
  printf("%8d%8d%8d\n", lines, words, chars);
}


$ ./a.out
The boy stood on the burning deck
shelling peanuts by the peck
^D
2 12 63
$
```

and

```
/* recognize tokens for the calculator and print them out */
%{
   enum yytokentype {
     NUMBER = 258,
     ADD = 259,
     SUB = 260,
     MUL = 261,
     DIV = 262,
     ABS = 263,
     EOL = 264
   };
   int yylval;
%}
%%
"+"    { return ADD; }
"-"    { return SUB; }
"*"    { return MUL; }
"/"    { return DIV; }
"|"    { return ABS; }
[0-9]+ { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n     { return EOL; }
[ \t]  { /* ignore whitespace */ }
.      { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int tok;
  while(tok = yylex()) {
    printf("%d", tok);
    if(tok == NUMBER) printf(" = %d\n", yylval);
    else printf("\n");
  }
}

$ ./a.out
a / 34 + |45
Mystery character a
262
258 = 34
259
263
258 = 45
264
^D
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex doesn't decide when the scanner will return (except for the default EOF rule). The scanner which it builds performs lexical actions in a loop until some action returns. So it is entirely up to you how you want to structure your scanner.

However, the classic yyparse/yylex processing model consists of the parser calling `yylex()` every time it needs a new token. So it expects `yylex()` to return immediately once it finds a token.

In your first code example, there is no parser and the scanner action is limited to printing out the token. While the example is perfectly correct, relying on the scanner loop to repeatedly execute actions, I'd prefer the second model even if you don't (yet) intend to add a parser, because it will make it easier to decouple token handling from token generation.

That doesn't mean that every lexical action will contain a return statement, though. Some lexical patterns correspond to non-tokens (comments and whitespace, for example), and the corresponding action will most likely do nothing (other than possibly recording input position) so that the scanner will continue to search fir a token to return.

(F)lex scanners are not easy to make into coroutines, so if a coroutine is really required (for example, to incrementally parse a asynchronous input), then another tool might be preferred.

Bison does offer the possiblity to generate a "push parser" in which the scanner *calls* the parser every time it finds a token, rather than *returning to* the parser. But neither the "push" nor the traditional "pull" model have anything to do with coroutines, IMHO, and the use of the word to describe parser/scanner interaction strikes me as imprecise and unuseful (although I have a lot of respect for the author you might be quoting.)

Comment: Thanks. (1) What is "coroutine" in your opinion? (2) Book `Flex & Bison` says "Most programs with flex scanners use the scanner to return a stream of tokens that are
handled by a parser. Each time the program needs a token, it calls yylex(), which reads
a little input and returns the token. When it needs another token, it calls yylex() again.
The scanner acts as a coroutine; that is, each time it returns, it remembers where it was,
and on the next call it picks up where it left off." What does "coroutine" do you think the book means?

Comment: @tim: I think John means "a function which maintains state". But that would describe almost any class object in an object-oriented programming language. It also describes the standard C I/O library (which retains state in the `FILE*` structure, or the Posix I/O system which keeps state in a kernel array indexed by file descriptor. It is not common to describe those things as "coroutines"

Comment: What is the definition of "coroutine" in general?

Comment: @tim: a coroutine (not just in my opinion) not only retains data state; it also retains *Control-Flow* state. A true coroutine (which is roughly a synchronized thread) doesn't just retain a single place in the control-fliw, which could be replaced with an enum and a switch; it retains an entire call stack. See Lua and/or Go for examples of languages with coroutines.

Comment: The still-useful Wikipedia has [an article on coroutines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

Comment: As I said recently responding to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527481/scanner-and-parser-interaction), we often use `scanf` to return a "stream of" numbers from stdin (one at a time, usually) but I can't recall anyone ever describing `scanf` as a "coroutine".